# Dynamically changing Highcharts Theme through Jquery code not working

Tags: jquery, json, variables, charts, highcharts

I am trying to create a variable options which will contain user chosen options as well as theme options for the chart that will be created on my webpage and then pass these in the chart:{options parameter. The chart does successfully show up, but the theme is not applied and I get the following error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (

I am not sure if I can succeed in passing the options to highcharts this way or if there is a problem in the code itself.

Here is my script:
http://pastebin.com/WFqTeGpG

Answer (score 0):

You should merge your theme options with options for the specific chart **or** use `setOptions`.

For the first one, example: http://jsfiddle.net/bwefs1ak/1/

```
var merged_options = $.extend(
    option1, 
    {
        data: {
            table: 'datatable'
        }
    }
);

$('#chartColumnChart').highcharts(merged_options);
```

For the second one, see [any demo with theme](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-basic/dark-unica). Just click "View visual theme" and the last line is responsible for setting theme.

Note: setting themes will affect only new charts, not existing ones.

Comment: I cannot merge the options because the data needs to be set using the function that gets the csv,                                          I dont understand why passing options: option1 doesnt already work thought, because all the other options are included in option1. For the last line of visual theme, It doesnt work because it changes all the charts in your page to the same theme.

Comment: Basically, all the theme options come from a file, example: dark-unica.js, and I paste all of the lines from it in my code and add the user chosen options inside it, then, the function in document.ready picks the data file and puts it inside the chart, and if i try to put all the options from the theme in that function, The first line of it will crash it because you cant use Highcharts.createElement inside that function. Therefore, I really need a way to pass all the options in my chart and also set the data separately.

Comment: Why you can not merge data? Data source doesn't matter in your case.. I guess? It doesn't work because you created some weird logic in JS, while JS doesn't work that way.. I'm pretty sure my solution above should resolve your issues, but or you explaining something bad or I don't understand something ;)